# Inkscape - How to wrap pattern around circle to make it look 3D?

Tags: inkscape

I am trying to make a basic cartoon soccer ball with a hexagon and pentagon pattern using Inkscape and I was watching this Adobe Illustrator tutorial because I could not find a tutorial for Inkscape: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=L9L6RdHBQtY and at the time 3:50 in the video the teacher uses some tool called 3D resolve and later Map Art to make the pattern look more 3D, how can we do the same in Inkscape so it looks like the pattern wraps around the ball (circle)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inkscape does not have any equivalent of Illustrator's 3D effects. You can cheat by using Extension Render > Polyhedron. Colorize the faces manually and supplement or clip the edges to circular. An example:

[image]

In the left the faces of the polyhedron are colored to black and white. They were ungrouped temporarily for easy access. All parts got a black stroke.

In the right a little smaller circle is used to clip the group of faces. A copy of that circle is placed behind the faces.

It's a fake - the seams are still straight, but it can create the wanted illusion if it's not the main subject of the image.